# how can i rotate a Texture2D in XNA game studio?

Tags: c#, xna

hi i have to rotate a Texture2D, but i dont know why.
its like a have a picture and i need to rotate it 180° because it's on the head and should be right.

the problem is, i need to do it before i use `spriteBatch.Draw`, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The texture will be rotated by 180 degree.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, null, Color.White, (float)Math.PI, new Vector2(texture.Width, texture.Height), 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

As also you can flip texture vertically using SpriteEffects:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, Position, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.FlipVertically, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: A spriteBatch origin argument of ``Vector2(texture.Width, texture.Height)`` is incorrect, this will pivot the texture along the angle specificed, not rotate it.  If you want a true 'rotation' in-place, you will need to use the middle of the texture as the origin point:  ``Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2)``, as an angle of more than pi/2 but less than pi will rotate the object outside of a clipping viewport (if any) with the origin you have specified here.  The origin correction becomes apparent in testing angles such as pi / 4 (45 degrees), and pi / 2 (90 degrees)

Answer (score 3):

The `Draw` method has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx) that will let you rotate the texture. I'm not sure I understand why you need to rotate the texture before drawing it. Scaling and rotating is normally done during drawing. As Joel point out the rotation is done using radians and you also need to mind the origin, which is the point you rotate around.

Comment: +1 Be aware that the angle is in radians not degrees. So 180 Degrees is PI. Here is a diagram. http://math.rice.edu/~pcmi/sphere/degrad.gif